# Using variables as source and target folders, cause error in .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab and in the root of my repository, I have a `Level4UI` project, I want to copy the binary files into a temporary directory after build completed.

So, I defined the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in my GitLab repository:

```
variables:
   EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER: '.\Level4UI\bin\Release2'
   EXE_LOCAL_TEMP_FOLDER: 'c:\NewLevel4'
stages:
- build

build:
   stage: build
   script:
     - nuget restore
     - msbuild MySolution.sln /t:Build  /p:Configuration=Release
     - 'xcopy /y $env:EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER\*.* $env:EXE_LOCAL_TEMP_FOLDER\'
```

When the build completes, I get following error:

> File not found - *.*
> 0 File(s) copied
> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 4

Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an `$env` to use your variables in a script section, just use them like this:

```
- 'xcopy /y $EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER\*.* $EXE_LOCAL_TEMP_FOLDER\'
```

Comment: I removed `$env`, but I get the same error.